# How can I maintain state in browser JavaScript across different page loads from the same site?

Tags: javascript

I need to do something very simple, i.e. maintain which panel bar item is highlighted, across different page loads. I'm using this as a menu, and it looks good with the selected menu item highlighted as soon as I click it, when when the link (page) for that menu item returns, the menu is reloaded and I lose this.

I don't really want to use ajax calls to manage session variables just for this if I can keep in local, but where else can I store this menu state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html), [local storage](http://caniuse.com/#search=storage) or you can encode the data in the URIs you link to (e.g. in the fragment identifier).